# Why am I getting an UncaughtSyntax Error

Tags: jquery, syntax, selector

I am trying to write a script that goes through all elements with an id of "toggleSelect".  It should add an onclick function that toggles the given select box based on the same element's rel attribute.

Example:

```
<input type="radio" name="button" value="toggle" id="toggleSelect" rel="example1">

<select name="example1" id="example1" DISABLED>
   <option>Test Option</option>
   <option>Test Option</option>
   <option>Test Option</option>
</select>
```

So basically when the radio button above is clicked, it should have an onclick function that enables the select box "example1".  I am getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." and I have no idea why.  Here is my code:

```
(function(){

   $("#toggleSelect").on("click", function(){
        idToggler = $(this).attr("rel");
        if($("#" + idToggler)).is(":disabled")){

            $("#" + idToggler.prop("disabled", false);

        } else {

            $("#" + idToggler.prop("disabled", true);

        }
    }); 
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: all elements with an id of "toggleSelect"....Bad practise of keeping multiple ids.

Comment: use a proper IDE for development... it should help you in detecting this king of problems

Comment: `$("#" + idToggler).prop` see before prop you have missed `)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
$("#toggleSelect").change(function() {
   idToggler = $(this).attr("rel");
    if($("#" + idToggler).is(":disabled")){

        $("#" + idToggler).removeAttr("disabled");

    } else {

        $("#" + idToggler).addAttr("disabled");

    }
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JBv56/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors in your code try the following code,

```
$(function() {
    $("#toggleSelect").on("change", function() {
        idToggler = $(this).attr("rel");
        if ($("#" + idToggler).is(":disabled")) {
            $("#" + idToggler).prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $("#" + idToggler).prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

[***Fiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/Tc56X/)

Answer (score 0):

here is the issue

```
if($("#" + idToggler)).is(":disabled")){
                     ↑
```

change it with

```
if( $("#" + idToggler).is(":disabled") ){
```

and here is the issue

```
$("#" + idToggler.prop("disabled", false);
                 ↑
```

it should be

```
$("#" + idToggler).prop("disabled", false);
```

and in else

```
$("#" + idToggler).prop("disabled", true);
```

and you need to add `$` sign before `(function(){`

like this

```
$(function(){
```

and finally you should use `on` like

```
$(document).on("change", "#toggleSelect", function() {
```